# How to force close my Android application?

Tags: android

Well apparently my android application doesnt close when I finish the activity so it there a way to force close it including any activity in my app that could be opened?

Comment: A better approach would be to figure out what it is that your app started that is kept alive after your activity ends.

Comment: Android keeps your android application alive, yet it doesn't do any processing (unless you are making it do so). This allows it to stay in memory and load up faster the next time it is activated by the user.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that the **process** is still alive does not mean that the **Activities** did not finish. The process might be kept for a while until the OS decides to kill it.

If you have activities that do not finish properly, make sure that you did not leave a thread running.

There is no method in the API to close an Application. It is up to the OS to terminate it when it is convenient. The last resource is to kill the process, but you should never need to use that in your apps.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that threads that you have started terminate, and then invoke [finish](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finish%28%29)

Btw. How have you verified that you activity isn't closing?

Answer (score 0):

Call [finish()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finish%28%29) at the point when you want it to close.  For example in [onPause()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPause%28%29) if you want it to finish when the activity is no longer the topmost one.

I personally suggest you simply make sure your app does not do anything when it is not active and let the system worry about 'finishing' it.